# Global Event for multiple types

Tags: vba, events, ms-word

Is it possible to write something like *global event listener*? I would like to have a listener for more objects (TextBox, CheckBox, OptionButton, Label, ...). and have the listener in my class. I have some normal events, so I my idea looks like this:

```
Public WithEvents eventGlobLst As <DontKnowWhat>SomeType</DontKnowWhat>

Sub setListener(controlObj As SomeType)
  Set eventGlobList = controlObj 
End Sub
```

From my run-method I'm calling sub which sets the listener

```
For Each pages In csDialgog.MultiPage.Pages
    For Each objectControl In pages.Controls

        Set eventClass = New ControlsClass
        eventClass.setListener objectControl
        universalObjectCollection.Add eventClass 
    Next
Next
```

This works fine with *classic* events. Finally I have some event handler:

```
Private Sub EventGlobLstnr_AfterUpdate()
    Functions.GlobalChange
End Sub
```

I would like to know if exist some ancestor of all objects which I can use. Or I must write the listener for every type separately and set them same `GlobalChange`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no, you're probably better off with self-writing code. Here's a good link that allows you to write into VBA editor

[Programming the VBA editor - Chip Pearson](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx)

**This code was taken from Chip Pearson:**

Creating An Event Procedure

This code will create a Workbook_Open event procedure. When creating an event procedure, you should use the CreateEventProc method so that the correct procedure declaration and parameter list is used. CreateEventProc will create the declaration line and the end of procedure line. It returns the line number on which the event procedure begins.

```
Sub CreateEventProcedure()
    Dim VBProj As VBIDE.VBProject
    Dim VBComp As VBIDE.VBComponent
    Dim CodeMod As VBIDE.CodeModule
    Dim LineNum As Long
    Const DQUOTE = """" ' one " character

    Set VBProj = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject
    Set VBComp = VBProj.VBComponents("ThisWorkbook")
    Set CodeMod = VBComp.CodeModule

    With CodeMod
        LineNum = .CreateEventProc("Open", "Workbook")
        LineNum = LineNum + 1
        .InsertLines LineNum, "    MsgBox " & DQUOTE & "Hello World" & DQUOTE
    End With
End Sub
```

Using `.CreateEventProc`, you can create an event for each elements that you want to "catch"
I believe this is the only way of achieving the goal you want.

Cheers,
kpark